# IMAP IDLE in Java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

Are there any Java IMAP libraries with support for the IDLE commands, other than Sun Java Mail?

I've been using Sun's JavaMail, and it works well, except that it has quite a bit of memory overhead.

Comment: I'm also planning to use the IDLE command of Sun's/Oracle JavaMail implementation. Can you elaborate on the memory issues? Did you end up using another implementation. If yes, which one?

Comment: @Theo, Oracle JavaMail used to create very large memory caches, even when not needed, for every folder.  Now it's a bit better.  It is fine for one person mail watcher, but not thousands at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This commercial product from Chilkat is an alternative: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-imap.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the IMAP directory from k9mail. But if all you want to do is IDLE and look for new mail, writing on top of TCP sounds like a good alternative. You can then use another job (perhaps running on another VM, even) to check every time the watcher notices anything.